# React hook dynamic name based on loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react hooks and I need to dynamically change the hook based on the loop's i value. I feel like there's a simple way to do it but can't find where. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
const [hanzi0, setHanzi0] = useState(0);
const [hanzi1, setHanzi1] = useState(0);
const [hanzi2, setHanzi2] = useState(0);
const [hanzi3, setHanzi3] = useState(0);

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        setHanzi0(tmpData[x].hanzi);                    
    }
```

Comment: Use this library I build https://www.npmjs.com/package/@alentoma/usestate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* dynamically look up a local variable name. It's just not a feature that javascript has.

But what you can do is look up a value in some data structure. Like, say, an array.

```
const [hanzis, setHanzis] = useState([0,0,0,0])
```

Now you can update that state like this:

```
const newHanzis = [...hanzis] // create a shallow copy of the array
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    newHanzis[i] = tmpData[i].hanzi
}
setHanzis(newHanzis)
```

If you need to dynamically access different states, then you don't actually have different states, you have one state that has enough complexity to hold many pieces of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if(i === 0) setHanzi0(tmpData[x].hanzi0);
  if(i === 1) setHanzi1(tmpData[x].hanzi1);
  if(i === 2) setHanzi2(tmpData[x].hanzi2);
  if(i === 3) setHanzi3(tmpData[x].hanzi3);                    
}
```

Comment: While that would technically work, a loop where you execute a different line of code for _every_ iteration of the loop isn't _really_ a loop. It's just a really confusing way to execute four lines of code...

Comment: Thank you, I had something like this before but it didn't feel right.